# Node not seeing funds

Tags: cardano

There was a transfer made which went through 72 hours ago, but the relay node is returning

```
No funds on the Address!
```

Is it because the node is not synced yet? Is there a way to verify the sync status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assumed your cardano-node config file has set the default EKG port 12788,
you can query the node for the current **BlockNo** by executing this command on your local node

`curl --silent -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://127.0.0.1:12788/' | jq -r .cardano.node.metrics.blockNum.int.val`

(You may first need to install `jq` on your system)

then go to https://pooltool.io/ and compare your nodes current value with the height reported there.